# How can I make my form to show only year (instead of d-m-y, mm:hh)?

Tags: twig, symfony-forms, symfony4

I am trying to make my form display only YEAR, however it shows me the whole set (eg. d-m-Y, mm:hh) since it's a DateTime. I believe there's some kind of filter but unfortunately all I have found does not work. Can you please help? Thank you!

In the FormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('titre')
        ->add('dateCreation', DateTimeType::class, date ('Y'))

    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option [format](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format) of this Type and do something like this

```
$builder->add('dateCreation', DateTimeType::class, [
    // this is actually the default format for single_text
    'format' => 'yyyy',
]);
```

See this [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#date-format) to